# JQuery how to get value of dynalically created inputs in table?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have looked at other sources on linked in and I am still unsure of how to find the value of my input when i dynamically create the input. I am creating an eCommerce store project and everytime a user adds something to the cart, on the cart page, I am showing every cart item. Each cart item then has a quantity input box so the user can change the quantity if they want (when they press the dynamically create button). Here is the code:

I have a foreach loop that determined how many items are needing to display and then one line from my code:

```
     <tr><td> <input type=\"number\" class =\"cartQuant\" name=\"quantity\" 
     data-row-quant=" + row['itemid'] + " value="+ row['quantity']+"><a 
     data-role='button' data-theme='a'  data-row-id=" + row['itemid'] + " 
     data-row-num=  " + i + " href='#'>UPDATE</a></td></tr>"
```

After I have a onclick event handler:

```
     $("#user_Cart a").on("click", clickHandler);
```

And the function it calls:

```
      function clickHandler() {
             var row = $('#user_Cart tr').eq($(this).attr("data-row-num"));
             var quantity = row.find('#cartQuant').val();
      }
```

I though the above would work by first getting the row, and then finding the input value form that row. I get an undefined as the value of quantity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your class selector is invalid, you should use `.` instead of `#`.

```
var quantity = row.find('.cartQuant').val();
```

`.` is a class selector and `#` is a id selector.

Comment: Hey, so I changed #cartQuant to .cartQuant but i am still getting undefined. When debugging the row value says it is storing a array. How would i access the different components of that array to get the value of my input?

Comment: That's what I thought so I tried to do row[0].find(' .cartQuant.va()') but i am being told that find is not a function when using row[0]. In the array objects are being stored. I need to be able to access the objects and the objects attributes like the value of the input field

Comment: @RW6 You are not getting an array but a jQuery object. You can simplify your code to `function clickHandler() {var quantity = $(this).siblings(".cartQuant").val();}`

Answer (score 1):

You may simplify your code:

on anchor click get the closest tr  than find the cartQuant and use that value.

Moreover, because you are adding on the fly new rows you need to delegate the event to a static ancestor (like document):

```js
$(document).on("click", "#user_Cart a", function(e) {
    var quantity = $(this).closest('tr').find('.cartQuant').val();
    console.log(quantity);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<table id="user_Cart">
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="number" class="cartQuant" name="quantity"
                   data-row-quant=row[itemid]" value="row[quantity]"><a
                data-role='button' data-theme="a" data-row-id="row[itemid]"
                data-row-num=" + i + " href='#'>UPDATE</a></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Hey I would do that but it basically depends on which tr the user updates. If the user wanted to update the second item int he cart I don't think the closest('tr') would work. Could I substitute the closest('tr') with somethi g else that can find the exact table row that was clicked?